# Gauss Divergence Theorem Calculation help

Tags: integration, vector-analysis

I am having trouble getting my head around what exactly is required in this problem.

Let $S$ be an arbitrary piecewise smooth, orientable, closed surface enclosing a region $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Calculate

$$\iint\limits_s a \cdot n\:\text{d}S$$

Where $n$ is an outwardly directed unit normal vector to $S$, and $a$ is a constant vector field in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I very much appreciate any help  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Gauss-Ostrogradski we have:
$$
\iint\limits_S a\:n\:\text{d}S=\iiint\limits_V \text{div}(a)\:\text{d}V=0,
$$
because 
$$
\text{div}(a) = \frac{\partial a_x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial a_y}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial a_z}{\partial z}=0.
$$

Comment: I thought this may have been all that was required however thought it was too simple.  Good to hear someone else came to the same conclusion as me!

Comment: Thanks user35603 for editing.